# Plotting Vectors in Mathematic at lat/long positions

Tags: vector, geodesy

I have some current data that I want to plot in Mathematica. The first two columns are the latitude and longitude respectively (longitudes are negative b/c it is west of the prime meridian and all latitudes are positive since it is north of the equator.) The third column is the u speed whereby a positive number indicates that this component is going towards the east and negative towards the west.  The fourth column is the v speed whereby a positive number indicates towards the north and negative is towards the south.  All values are in cm/second.

59.666667  -37.333333   -4.232386  -12.291741
 59.666667  -37.000000   -4.232386  -12.291741
 59.666667  -36.666667   -4.232386  -12.291741
 52.666667  -42.666667   18.513031    4.274070
 52.666667  -42.333333   19.890438    2.090569
 52.666667  -42.000000   19.696155    3.472964

Comment: What version of Mathematica do you have?

Comment: Try looking at the documentation for `GeoGraphics`, `GeoPosition`, and `GeoDisplacement` if you're using v10.

Comment: I have Mathematica 9 unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica v 10

```
data = {{59.666667, -37.333333, -4.232386, -12.291741}, {59.666667, \
-37., -4.232386, -12.291741}, {59.666667, -36.666667, -4.232386, \
-12.291741}, {52.666667, -42.666667, 18.513031, 
   4.27407}, {52.666667, -42.333333, 19.890438, 
   2.090569}, {52.666667, -42., 19.696155, 3.472964}};
Manipulate[
 GeoGraphics[
  Arrow[{GeoPosition[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}], 
      GeoPosition[{#[[1]] + scale #[[3]], #[[2]] + 
         scale #[[4]]}]}] & /@ data, 
  GeoRange -> Quantity[range, "Miles"], GeoProjection -> "Albers", 
  GeoGridLines -> Automatic], {{scale, 0.5}, .2, 1}, {{range, 1500}, 
  200, 2000, 100}, SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you again. Would you mind stepping through the code line by line and explaining what each line is doing? Thanks!